Formatting eg. Duration in a way that units and respective values are formatted separately
Sorry for a lame question, I'm a designer starting with SwiftUI so you know. I'm trying to do one thing and I just can't - so if any of you guys could help me out, I'd really appreciate it.
So I have this counter for different values with different units (kilometres, duration, etc). It reads, eg. "2KM" above and "TIME" below.

Now I totally randomly typed this:
private let totalDistance = Measurement(value: 2.5, unit: UnitLength.kilometers)

Then this:
Text(totalDistance, format: .measurement(width: .narrow))

Now what I'd like to do is to format the unit (in this example, the KM's) independently of the value. In particular I'm trying to add a different font style to the units, like .caption os .subheadline.
Is it doable in the garden of SwiftUI?

In SwiftUI, it is possible! Divide the measurement into two Text views, one for the value and one for the unit. Apply distinct styles to each Text view to format the value and the unit independently.
For instance, I utilised totalDistance.value for the data portion and totalDistance.unit.symbol for the unit (KM in this case).
For both the value and the unit, you can add a separate typeface modifier.
Formatting of the Value: You can change the format of the value by using the specifier "%.1f" to display one decimal place.
The appearance of the numerical value and the unit can be independently controlled in this way.
This is illustrated below.
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    private let totalDistance = Measurement(value: 2.5, unit: UnitLength.kilometers)

    var body: some View {
        let formattedValue = totalDistance.value
        let formattedUnit = totalDistance.unit.symbol

        VStack {
            HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline) {
                // Value with one style
                Text("\(formattedValue, specifier: "%.1f")")
                    .font(.largeTitle) // Customize the font for the value

                // Unit with another style
                Text(formattedUnit)
                    .font(.caption) // Customize the font for the unit
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
            }
            
            Text("TIME") // Example text below
                .font(.headline)
                .padding(.top)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}


Thank you brother, you're such a boss!
